# Add view to open Window in titanium

Tags: javascript, iphone, xml, model-view-controller, titanium

I have 3 views: v1.xml, v2.xml, v3.xml.
v1.xml has a button B1. When user clicks button B1, it opens v2.xml.
v2.xml has another button B2. When user clicks button B2, it opens v3.xml.

I created a window in v1.xml. When I click on button B2, I want to add view v3 to the existing window and I do not want to create a new window. I am unable to use the window reference that I created in v1.xml as I am working in v2.xml file now.

My code:

```
V1.xml


<Alloy>
   <Window id="main_window">
      <View id="v1">
         <Button id="B1" />
      </View>
   </Window>
</Alloy>

V2.xml

<Alloy>
    <View id="v2">
        <Button id="B2" />
    </View>
</Alloy>

V3.xml

<Alloy>
    <View id="v3">
        <Label id="l3" text="test label"/>
    </View>
</Alloy>


V1.js

$b1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var view = Alloy.createController("V2").getView();
    $.main_window.remove(v1);
    $.main_window.add(view);
});

V2.js

$.b2.addEventListener('click', function(){
   var view = Alloy.createController("V3").getView();
   //Add this view to main_window

});
```

Comment: in V1.js , try changing `$.main_window.add(v2);` to `$.main_window.add(view);`

Comment: Oh yeah...that's what I actually had..but this doesn't address my problem though

Comment: Is this even compiling? There are a fair amount of errors that would not pass the Alloy pre-compile stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to pass referance to window created in V1 when you are creating V2 controller:

   **V1.js**

   ```
   $b1.addEventListener('click', function() {
       var view = Alloy.createController("V2", { main_window: $.main_window }).getView();
       $.main_window.remove(v1);
       $.main_window.add(view);
   });
   ```

   **V2.js**

   ```
   var args = arguments[0] || {};
   var main_window = args.main_window;

   $.b2.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var view = Alloy.createController("V3").getView();
      main_window.add(view);
   });
   ```
2. Or you can create just one event listener and pass it as argument:

   **V1.js**

   ```
   var currentView;
   var replaceViews = function(view) {
       currentView && $.main_window.remove(currentView);
       $.main_window.add(view);
       currentView = view;
   }

   $.b1.addEventListener('click', function() {
       var view = Alloy.createController('V2', { delegate: replaceViews }).getView();
       replaceViews(view);
   });
   ```

   **V2.js**

   ```
   var args = arguments[0] || {};
   var replaceViews = args.delegate;

   $.b2.addEventListener('click', function() {
       var view = Alloy.createController('V3').getView();
       replaceViews(view);
   });
   ```
3. The last option would be setting $.main_window to Alloy.Globals and creating global function.

Here you can read more about [passing arguments to Alloy Controller](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers-section-34636384_AlloyControllers-PassingArguments) and [Alloy.Globals](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Alloy-property-Globals).